# Assign lambda expression as a function in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm new to c# but coming from c++ we had something that you could do which is inline create lambda functions. I'm trying to something like this, but is not working. Can someone show me how to do something like this?

```
playButton.Click += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => (getController.startPlay());
```

Comment: playButton.Click += (sender, e) => getController.startPlay();

Comment: Thanks @vasily.sib

Comment: You are wellcome! Btw, in case you need to do more then 1 method to call, don't forget the brackets: `playButton.Click += (sender, e) => { DoThis(); DoThat(); getController.startPlay(); }`

Comment: @vasily.sib thanks again, if you want I can give you the credit for the correct answer since you answered correctly and were first.

Comment: Tip for the future, when you're posting questions here on Stack Overflow then try to avoid "it is not working". Try to say **how** it is not working, like if you get a compiler error, runtime exception, incorrect or no behavior, etc. **Be specific**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use a block for the body of the lambda in some cases, most notably when you need to execute multiple statements:

```
playButton.Click += (s, e) => { getController.startPlay(); Trace.Write("Play..."); };
```

For lambdas that really are just a single expression, you can omit the block (no need for the parentheses either). E.g.:

```
Func<int> someDelegate = () => 42;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `{}` needs to be there? I tried it without the `{}` with delegates and it works.

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah, seems to be working without it. I'm not sure if it's something that changed in some version of the C# compiler or if the requirements for when you need the block are different than I remembered...

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work except for one thing, when you add parenthesis, `(...)`, the part between has to be an *expression*, ie. "something that *evalues to something*"

So this:

```
... => (getController.startPlay());
```

will give you:

> CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Note that even if the method returns something, it will then likely not automagically fit the delegate you're trying to use for the event, in which case there will be a similar error but a different cause, so making `startPlay` return a value won't work either.

In any case, to get it working you simply have to remove the parenthesis:

```
... => getController.startPlay();
```

The code should then work just as you expect it to.